# WCF Per Session and Blocking Collection for Logging

Tags: wcf, logging, servicebehavior

Anyway to log a Per Session Wcf Service to a single file without causing file locking issues or should it be a seperate application?

Comment: What kind of logging are you using? are you directly opening a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Microsoft Practices Enterprise Library

[Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx)

Comment: Fairly vauge answer - more detail would be helpful.